# From where comes /run/resolvconf/interface/eth0.dhclient file

Tags: networking, resolv.conf, dhcpd, resolvconf

I'm searching for original configuration file that is the source for generating `/run/resolvconf/interface/eth0.dhclient` file.

That file contain DNS server names and the domain name for my machine. I'm able to change them but the change are not persistent (other config files are updated by using `resolvconf -u`). However, the older values are restored after a restart of the server.

Network Manager is not installed on the server that is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After few hours more and more investigation, I got to conclusion that the domain name is set through our provider DHCP server. I searched a way to bypass it for the domain name without any success by:

1. adding `dns-domain-name` in `iface` configuration for `eth0` in `eth0.cfg` file:

   ```
   auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp dns-domain-name projet-okinawa.org
   ```
2. adding `send domain-name` and uncommenting `supersede` for the same domain-name in `dhclient.conf`
3. setting the fully qualified name in `/etc/hosts` for ip `127.0.0.1`

I got any error but never the correct fqdn for the server. I got either the provider dhcp one, or this error:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Do read http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html it will explain a lot ;-)  " Normally  resolvconf  is  run  only by hook scripts attached to network
       interface configurers such as pppd(8) (for  ppp  interfaces),  to  DHCP  clients  such  as dhclient(8), to ifup(8) and ifdown, and to DNS caches     such as dnsmasq(8) (for the loopback interface).   These  hook  scripts  furnish  resolvconf  with  information about nameservers.  "

Comment: Thank you but already read carefully this documentation and I didn't found anything in these scripts that let me understand from where the domain name was set ... I got the eth0.dhclient from this deep exploration into all this stuff (came from /etc/hosts ... the many resolv.conf, etc ...).  Sure I missed something ...

Comment: For sure the domain name is set through the DHCP. My setting is : auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp. I tried pre-domain and pre-domain-name to force my own domain name withou success. I tried also to define it in the dhclient.conf also without success. Some changes causes the system to fail on restart and a reinitialization was necessary. I would like to avoid to use fix ip address and prefer to force only our own domain name but it seem to me that fix ip is unfortunately the only way at the moment. Any comment or recommandation about ?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf`

usually writes `/run/resolvconf/interface/eth0.dhclient` when the DHCP client handles IP address updates.

This may also be handy:

14.04 default (minified) `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

Plus, `man dhclient.conf` `man dhcp-options` `man dhcp-eval`

I would advise against hacking resolvconf or dhclient.conf, and set everything needed as a dhclient.conf include script using a directive like so

```
script "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.d/this-is-a-foo-corp-or-my-network-managed-system";
```

Ubuntu doesn't handle every single, enterprisey edge-case (but does get most common ones), so a minor change could be needed in rare situations.